# Batch file that compares ID's of lines in two files and writes it to another file| Using AWK

Tags: batch-file, awk, compare, lines, identifier

I have two files which contains **Texts** and **Descriptions**:

```
**File1.txt:**
"ID1" "Text text text text" "True"
"ID2" "Text text text text" "True"
"ID3" "Text text text text" "True"
"ID4" "Text text text text" "True"

**File2.txt:**
"ID1" "Description description description" "True"
"ID2" "Description description description" "True"
"ID6" "Description description description" "True"
"ID7" "Description description description" "True"
"ID3" "Description description description" "True"
```

and I want to write only these **descriptions** which has the same IDs as **Texts**:

```
**File3.txt:**
"ID1" "Description description description" "True"
"ID2" "Description description description" "True"
"ID3" "Description description description" "True"
```

another file must contain **texts** that have IDs from file3.txt

```
**File4.txt**
"ID1" "Text text text text" "True"
"ID2" "Text text text text" "True"
"ID3" "Text text text text" "True"
```

---

As you can see, I want to compare two files and write lines with the same id only. I want to use AWK software in .Bat file to do this but i don't really know how to start. **There're tabs between quotes "ID" "text" "True".**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk one-liner generates two files in one shot:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a{print a[$1]>"file4.txt";print}' file1 file2 >file3.txt
```

if the separator is `<TAB>`

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR.....'
```

Comment: my cmd says: "invalid char ''' in expression"
I'm using windows

Comment: I tested the cmd in answer just now, it worked with my gawk under bash and zsh. I don't have windows system, cannot do that test. @user3151135

Comment: maybe there's another way to do this by using other software?

Comment: @user3151135 sorry I am not familiar with windows text processing tool set. cannot give further suggestion. ... oh, you could try Ms-word or Ms-Excel.

Comment: is it really possible to do by word? I've tried to do it in Excel but it was too hard.

Comment: ok, it works. I can't use double quotes inside double quotes, so I needed to escape them. Take a look:
gawk "NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a{print a[$1]>\""file4.txt\"";print}" file1.txt file2.txt >file3.txt

Comment: @user3151135 in answer I have `<single>...<double>...<double>...<single>` why not just cp and paste?

Comment: @Kent in Windows, single quotes doesn't have any special meaning. Correct quoting in Windows: `awk "NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a{print a[$1]>\"file4.txt\";print}" file1 ...`